# Time Complexity of Insertion Sort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, insertion-sort

**Could anyone explain why insertion sort has a time complexity of Θ(n²)?**

I'm fairly certain that I understand time complexity as a concept, but I don't really understand how to apply it to this sorting algorithm.  Should I just look to mathematical proofs to find this answer?

Comment: Writing the mathematical proof yourself will only strengthen your understanding. Often the trickiest parts are actually the setup. For example, first you should clarify if you want the worst-case complexity for an algorithm or something else (e.g. average-case complexity). Second, you want to define what counts as an actual operation in your analysis. For comparison-based sorting algorithms like insertion sort, usually we define comparisons to take `O(1)` time and swaps to take `O(1)` time. You can justify to yourself whether that is a valid metric. From that point on just apply the definition

Answer (score 11):

On average each insertion must traverse half the currently sorted list while making one comparison per step.  The list grows by one each time.

So starting with a list of length 1 and inserting the first item to get a list of length 2, we have average an traversal of .5 (0 or 1) places.  The rest are 1.5 (0, 1, or 2 place), 2.5, 3.5, ... , n-.5 for a list of length n+1.

This is, by simple algebra, 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n - n*.5 = (n(n+1) - n)/2 = n^2 / 2 = O(n^2)

Note that this is the average case.  In the worst case the list must be fully traversed (you are always inserting the next-smallest item into the ascending list).  Then you have 1 + 2 + ... n, which is still O(n^2).

In the best case you find the insertion point at the top element with one comparsion, so you have 1+1+1+ (n times) =  O(n).

Comment: Good answer. I just like to add 2 things:  
1.  A nice set of notes by Peter Crummins exists here http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-one/   
2.  In the worst case, we have the most insidious of inputs. That is the list is completely reverse-sorted. So each iteration will take 'j' traversals. The formula for calculating the time T(n) = sum(\theta(j)) for j = 2:n. (assuming list is indexed from 1)

Comment: @MhAcKN Exactly.  This is why sort implementations for big data pay careful attention to "bad" cases.  You _generally_ (and this is a very rough rule of thumb) don't want to use insertion sort if the data can possibly grow to more than a hundred or so.

Comment: Thanks Gene. Was working out the time complexity theoretically and i was breaking my head what Theta in the asymptotic notation actually quantifies. So i suppose that it quantifies the number of traversals required. Just a small doubt, what happens if the > or = operators are implemented in a more efficient fashion in one of the insertion sorts. Then how do we change Theta() notation to reflect this. or am i over-thinking?

Comment: @MhAcKN You are right to be concerned with details. \O, \Omega, \Theta et al concern relationships between _functions_ not run times. When we use them to describe runtimes, glossing over the nature of the input and other sloppiness makes for problems. In most characterizations of sort algoritms the function being described with \O, \Theta, etc is "number of comparisons vs. number of input data for data causing worst case performance".  So the run time of the comparison has already been factored out of the analysis. With this definition, insertion sort is (as you describe) \Theta(n^2).

Comment: The best case is actually one less than N: in the simplest case one comparison is required for N=2, two for N=3 and so on. For the worst case the number of comparisons is N*(N-1)/2: in the simplest case one comparison is required for N=2, three for N=3 (1+2), six for N=4 (1+2+3) and so on.

Comment: @OlofForshell Well, the -1 depends on details of implementation.Using index comparison to stop the insertion point search then there are N-1 key comparisons and N index comparisons. Using a sentinel, there are N key comparisons only.

Answer (score 1):

It only applies to arrays/lists - i.e. structures with O(n) time for insertions/deletions. It can be different for other data structures. For example, for skiplists it will be O(n * log(n)), because binary search is possible in O(log(n)) in skiplist, but insert/delete will be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case time complexity of **Insertion Sort** algorithm is O(n^2). 
Worst case of insertion sort comes when elements in the array already stored in decreasing order and you want to sort the array in increasing order.

Suppose you have an array

```
Step 1 => | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | No. of comparisons = 1  |  No. of movements = 1 
Step 2 => | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | No. of comparisons = 2  |  No. of movements = 2
Step 3 => | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | No. of comparisons = 3  |  No. of movements = 3
Step 4 => | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | No. of comparisons = 4  |  No. of movements = 4
```

T(n) = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + ---------- + 2(n-1)

T(n) = 2 * ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + -------- + (n-1))

T(n) = 2 * (n(n-1))/2

T(n) = O(n^2)