# Time Complexity of the Recursive Fuction Which Uses Swap Operation Inside

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

[image]

I am confused to calculate this function's time complexity.

Here is my approach:
In the worst case, the recursive call has O(n) complexity and the while loop(bubble sort) has O(n^2) complexity. Overall will be O(n^2).
In the best case, the array is already sorted so bubble sort has O(n) complexity and the recursive call has O(1), overall will be O(n).

Comment: If it helps, just replace the recursion with a for-loop that iterates `n` times.

Comment: This is insertion sort, written in a recursive form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827193/time-complexity-of-insertion-sort?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Swap is `O(1)` complexity, because you can do it in `3` operations

```
swapping i and j
c = A[i]
A[i] = A[j]
A[j] = c
```

This algorithm works like insertion sort, it sorts the prefix at every call. If you have a prefix of size `i` currently in the function, you are sure that `i-1` size prefix is already sorted, then you have to insert `A[i - 1]` (assuming `0` indexing) to it's correct position by swapping adjacent elements.

This is `O(n^2)` time complexity because if you have reversely sorted array, then you have to do `i` operations for each `i+1` prefix. So it's something like `1 + 2 + 3 + .. n - 1` this sum is `O(n^2)`, it's actually equal to `n * (n - 1) / 2`. But it can't be said that it does exactly that many operations, because you don't know exactly how machine works, so `O(n^2)` is a good bound.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but the algorithm is insertion sort rather than bubble sort.